# Optimizing HTML5 video for best quality

Tags: encoding, video-quality, compression, webvideos

I have a 3 minute video I'd like to embed on a web page. The problem is that despite best efforts, the file size of the video ends up being over 30 mb. I would like the size to be near 10 mb. I have over-compressed the video to the point where it is barely watchable.

So far I have used fast start encoding, compressed bit rate and smaller frame size as low as 300 width, exported for web including moving the moov atom to the beginning. Still the file is too large.

How does one get hd mp4 video small enough for web without losing an insane amount of quality?

Comment: 10MB for 3 mins == 450 kbps. For live-action 720p that's not achievable. Recommended rate is 5 times that.

Comment: For lowest bitrate you have to use H265 codec, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382568/h-265-hevc-web-browser-support

In any case you need to spend as much processing power on the encoding as you can. Also you should use software encoders instead of NVENC, Quicksync or similar. There are many tuts out there

https://superuser.com/questions/582198/how-can-i-get-high-quality-low-size-mp4s-like-the-lol-release-group But to be honest i dont really get your question. Please edit your question and add some details so it can be acutally answered

Comment: You might be able to encode it as a black and white gif and package the audio separate.  Probably would be annoying to keep them in sync though.  Honestly I don't think what you are stating is possible.